# Solr synonym graph filter not working after other filter

Tags: solr, synonym

I'm trying to convert `15.6"` searches to `15.6 inch`. The idea was first replace `15.6"` to `15.6 "` and then match the `"` with the synonym rule `" => inch`.
I created the type definition:

```
<fieldType name="text_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern='^([0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?)(")$' replacement="$1 $3" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

but it's not working! If I input `15.6"` I get `15.6 "`, but when I input `15.6 "` I get what I want - `15.6 inch`.

Why doesn't it work? Am I missing something?

EDIT:

Solr Analysis:
[image: Not working]

[image: Working]

Comment: Couldn't you just replace it with `$1 inch` in that case, instead of going via the synonyms? Use the `Analysis` page under Solr's Admin to see exactly how the tokens are processed for each step - it should be able to tell you what everything looks like after the patternreplacefilter is done. Looks like have subgroups instead subgroups, so `$3` is probably wrong unless you move the ending `)`).

Comment: I guess I could, but I might want to use the PatternReplaceFilter for characters other than `"` later. On the other hand, the approach above seems perfectly logical, except that it doesn't work, so I wanted to know if there is some reasoning behind it...

Comment: That's why you're going to use the Solr Admin's Analysis page to see exactly what happens for each step in your chain - the problem should hopefully be obvious then.,

Comment: Thanks for you interest. I edited my post now with the Solr Analysis. I had already done it before, but couldn't really deduce anything from it.

Comment: I think I get it now. After PatternFilter `15.6 "` is still one token, and clearly `15.6 "` is not the same as `"`. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `15.6 "` is still a single token after your pattern replace filter - just creating a token with a space in it will not split it.

You can see that it's still kept as a single token as there is no `|` on the line (which separates the tokens).

Add a Word Delimiter Filter after it (it seems from your analysis chain that you already have one, it's just not included in your question), or, better, do the replacement in a `PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory` *before* the tokenizer gets the task to split the input into separate tokens:

```
<analyzer>
  <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern='^([0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?)(")$' replacement="$1 $3" />
  <tokenizer ...>
```

You might have to massage the pattern matcher a bit (i.e. lose the ^ and $ which isn't respected by Solr any way, iirc) depending on your input (since it'll now be applied to the whole input string - make sure that "Macbook 15.6" 256GB" is matched approriately).

Comment: I tried doing the pattern matching before the tokenization, but it seems that Solr automatically invokes tokenizers first. I also tried adding another tokenizer, but Solr didn't like that.

Comment: You have to add it as a `charFilter`. This is important. If you just add a filter, it'll be invoked in sequence after the tokenizer. Char filters are applied first, then the tokenizer, then the filters. The WordDelimiterGraphFilter can do some of the operations a tokenizer can as well.